# Can I use libssh with SSH2?

Tags: c, libssh

I am trying to use libssh to execute ***[show_remote_files(session)](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_command.html#remote_command)*** on remote host. But it gets stuck and gives the following output.

I used ***get_ssh_version*** and it shows **2**.

Can I not use ssh2 with libshh? How can I tell my system(linux) to use ssh1 instead?

> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.134908, 1] ssh_connect:  libssh 0.6.1 (c) 2003-2014 Aris Adamantiadis, Andreas Schneider, and libssh contributors. Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYING file for information about your rights, using threading threads_noop
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.170424, 2] ssh_socket_connect:  Nonblocking connection socket: 3
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.170466, 2] ssh_connect:  Socket connecting, now waiting for the callbacks to work
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.294109, 1] socket_callback_connected:  Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.330777, 1] ssh_client_connection_callback:  SSH server banner: SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_5.3
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.330815, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  Analyzing banner: SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_5.3
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.330827, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 5.3 (50300)
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.492126, 2] ssh_packet_dh_reply:  Received SSH_KEXDH_REPLY
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.493287, 2] ssh_client_dh_reply:  SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.493324, 2] ssh_packet_newkeys:  Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.493604, 2] ssh_packet_newkeys: Signature verified and valid ssh_get_version = 2 before after
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.495199, 2] channel_open:  Creating a channel 43 with 64000 window and 32768 max packet
>
> [2014/09/28 11:21:02.602802, 1] ssh_packet_unimplemented:  Received SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED (sequence number 3)

`int rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);`

This line blocks the code when session is in blocking mode.